# Having problem with solr query syntax

Tags: php, sorting, lucene, solr

Everyone I have started working with solr PHP from about 2 or 3 days this is working perfect so far but having some issues with the sorting and random records, Also im using Lucene syntax, Here is the query

(cf_title: nokia OR cf_description: nokia) AND (cf_power_ad: 1 OR cf_power_deal: 1) AND cf_city : Lahore AND sort : cf_addeddate desc

Can some one please help me with the sorting and random records?, Thankyou!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort order should be given not as part of the query but as separate parameter named sort.
Please take a look at this: http://lucene.apache.org/solr/tutorial.html#Sorting

To get random sort order you should use RndomSortField as described here:
http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/schema/RandomSortField.html